# How do I make text show up next to my picture when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a paragraph of text appear next to each image after I pick it. Currently, all I have is the image showing up after I click it. I don't know how to add text next to the image that only shows up when it is clicked on. I'm new to programming so anything could help. If you guys need more information, let me know. Thanks.

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
   var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
   var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
   expandImg.src = imgs.src;
   imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
   expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'tekoregular';
    src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
    src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
    src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }
  
  .topnav {
    background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-weight: 900;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
    left: 2%;
  }
  
  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  
  .topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  /* Style the images inside the grid */
  .column img {
    opacity: 0.85; 
    cursor: pointer; 
  }
  
  .column img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  /* The expanding image container */
  .container {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width:50%;
  }
  
  /* Expanding image text */
  #imgtext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  /* Closable button inside the expanded image */
  .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .row{
    position: absolute;
    top:600px;
  }
  .testtext{
    color:black;
    background-color: grey;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
        <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
        <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
      </header>
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <h2>Tabbed Image Gallery</h2>
        <p>Click on the images below:</p>
        <div class="container">
          <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
          <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
          <div id="imgtext"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
        </div>
      </div>
      
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image takes up the entire screen. How can you display text "next to the image", when the text would be off the screen?

Comment: The image should be smaller. I apologize. I'll update my code here

Comment: @terrymorse the new edits should reflect this change. I'm still having trouble though, if you could help me.

Comment: Are you looking to display the alt text ("Nature" for baby yoda, "Snow", etc) beside the image, or do you want to add some more text like a whole paragraph (e.g. "here you can see the FDS logo") beside the image?

Comment: @rf19 I made some changes that display a div to the right of the expanded image, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes and additions. Here's the expanded image with the paragraph section next to it:

[image]

The new expanded image block with side paragraph:

```html
  <div id="expanded-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"
        class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
      <div id="imgtext"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="img-paragraph">
      <p>image paragraph content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Plus some changes and additions to the CSS.

See the snippet for complete details.

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  
  // use 'display:table-cell' to keep elements side-by-side
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
  imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  opacity: 0.85;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
}


/* Expanding image text */

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  width: 30%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
}
```

```html
<header class="topnav" id="topnav">
  <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
  <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
  <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
  <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
</header>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Tabbed Image Gallery</h2>
  <p>Click on the images below:</p>
  <div id="expanded-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
      <div id="imgtext"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="img-paragraph">
      <p>image paragraph content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/Petngc9GmDGVfvqWtZW1uw--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjt3PTcwNTtoPTM4MC43/https://s.yimg.com/uu/api/res/1.2/p2FH9i2oATkHA6O0ucuC9A--~B/aD0yMTY7dz00MDA7c209MTthcHBpZD15dGFjaHlvbg--/https://media.zenfs.com/en/prnewswire.com/d908212583d777d158af74cb171ec897"
      alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://engineering.wustl.edu/news/PublishingImages/141020_jwb_brookings_007-1915x768.jpg?RenditionID=1" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/McKelvey-courtyard.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the image is not taking up all the space inside the container by removing its width 100%:

```
<img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
```

change to:

```
<img id="expandedImg">
```

Then you can set a different width for your image inside the css and remove the absolute positioning from the text.

You have loads of options here to make them appear side by side but for wrapping text around pictures you can use floats.

Also don't forget to change the text color as it won't be visible when white on this white background.

Final css for the image and the text:

```
#imgtext {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  float:left;
}
#expandedImg{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```